# Unable to Save Data in MySQL table in RaspberryPi using python

Tags: python, mysql

I am stuck in a very difficult problem of not able to store data in the table of MySQL installed in raspberryPi using Python. I am just trying to save Hello World. Please go through the program i have used and the results i am getting.
Please help where i am going wrong. Thank you in advance.

import MySQLdb

try:

db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","int3rneT@","intruder")

print("Success")

curs=db.cursor()

print("success1")

with db:

z="HelloWorld"

print(z)

print("success2")

curs.execute("""INSERT into PIR1 values (%s)""",(z))

print("success3")

db.commit()

print("success4")

except:

print("not connecting")

---

The result i am getting is :

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 testingDataBaseConnection.py

Success

success1

not connecting

From the result, i concluded that code is not running after "with db".

---

I have created table PIR1  as below:

create TABLE PIR1(gpsData  VARCHAR(200));

### I am highly doubtful about the above line whether it is correct or not.

When i run show tables command, i get this, which concludes the table is created.

MariaDB [intruder]> show tables;

+--------------------+

| Tables_in_intruder |

+--------------------+

| PIR1               |

+--------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try printing the exception to see what went wrong?

```
except Exception as error: 
    print(error)
```

Comment: After executing the program, i am getting the below results:pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 testingDataBaseConnection.py
Success
success1
__exit__